# converting PSD to HTML

Tags: html, psd

I got a hold of some PSD files that by designer created. They contain buttons and sliders and other web UI elements.
How do I convert parts of the PSD to CSS/web elements? The PSD was properly created in order to be able to do this. I also have an EPS file that contains web UI elements and I don't even know how to open it. What software do I need and what is the process to get HTML elements out of both files?

Thanks!!

Comment: There are services that will convert PSD to HTML for a fee. An example is [PixelCrayons](http://xhtml.pixelcrayons.com/).

Comment: did you get your answer?? If YES, Can you tell me???

Answer (score 3):

You slice the various images you need out of the graphic, and then assemble them by writing HTML and CSS (by hand).

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic software that converts PSD to html/css. Hire somebody to do it for you. It is cheap. There are many online services. Just search for psd to html.